# Why does the site redirect to sign in component when I refresh website in list component in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, vuex, apollo

I made a store and a router in Vue and when I sign in the router redirects me to the list component, so the problem is when I'm in list component and I refresh the website it redirects me to the sign in component. This URL is displayed after refreshing the website - http://localhost:8080/sign-in?redirect=/list

**Vuex**

```
actions: {
  async fetchLogin({ commit, state }) {
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
         commit('loadingStatus', true)
        try {
          const response = await provider.clients.graphqlClient.mutate({
            mutation:
              gql`mutation Login($email:String!, $password:String!)
              {
                login(email:$email, password:$password){
                  token
                }
              }`, variables: {
                email: state.login.email,
                password: state.login.password
              }
          })
            const token = response.data.login.token
            commit('setToken', token)
            localStorage.setItem('apollo-token', token)
        } catch (error) {
            commit('loadingStatus', false)
            console.log('error-message', error.graphQLErrors)          
            state.graphqlError = error.graphQLErrors[0].message
          }
        resolve()
      })
    },
},

getters: {
  isAuthenticated(state) {
      return state.token !== null
  }
}
```

**Router**

```
{
    path: "/sign-in",
    name: "SignIn",
    component: SignIn
},
{
    path: "/list",
    name: "List",
    component: List,
    meta: { requiresAuth: true }
}

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const isUserLoggedIn = store.getters.isAuthenticated
  const getToken = localStorage.getItem("apollo-token")
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!getToken || !isUserLoggedIn) {
      next({
            path: '/sign-in',
            query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
          })
    } else {
       next()
      }
  } else {
      next()
    }
})
```

**SignIn.vue**

```
<script>
methods: {
    submitForm() {
      this.$store.dispatch("fetchLogin")
        .then(() => this.$router.push('/list'))
        .then(() => this.$store.commit("loadingStatus", false))
}
</script>
```